# cocoa-applescript: running handler or command every few seconds

Tags: handler, applescript-objc

In normal applescript, the script is executed down the page, and so any code in loops for every 5 seconds will only run while the loop is running - there is no way to have a single function run every few second **regardless** of what the script is currently doing or where it is in the script (that I know of). In cocoa-applescript, however, is there a way to run a handler every 5 seconds, at all times, no matter what it is currently doing? Here is what it should be doing in my cocoa-applescript app:

```
on checkInternetStrength()
    do shell script "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I | grep 'agrCtlRSSI:'" -- this being the script which returns the line containing the signal strength
    set SignalStrength to result
    set RSSIcount to (count of characters in SignalStrength)
    set SignalStrength to ((characters 18 thru RSSIcount of SignalStrength) as string) as integer -- this to turn SignalStrength into just the number and not the whole output line
    set SignalStrength to (100 + SignalStrength) as integer
    set SignalBar's setIntValue_(SignalStrength) -- SignalBar being the Level Indicator described below
end checkInternetStrength
```

Summed up, it runs the airport command to check internet connection, turns this into a number from 1 to 100 and uses this on an NSLevelIndicator (100 maximum) to show current signal strength graphically. Now, there is no point having this run *once* or when you hit a button - that is an option, but it would be nice if it updated itself every, say, 5 seconds with the realtime value. So is there any way to have a process which runs every 5 seconds to do this, while still enabling full functionality of the rest of the script and interface - i.e. as a background process? Comment if you need more extracts from the script.

### Example

In Unity-C# scripting, the **'void Update() {code}'** will run the code within it every frame while doing everything else simultaneously, so a cocoa-applescript version of this might be an answer, if anyone knows.

Answer (score 0):

I Dont believe this is possible but what I had a similar problem before, what i do, I have an external applescript applicaion that is hidden the repeats the commands, the only problem is, it wont send it back to the app, you'll have to make the external applescript app do it, like
    display notification, etc..., in the applescript apps "Info.plist" you can add this:

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

To make the app run invisibly, but sorry i dont think you can run a handler in the app its self